# In soap UI, How Can I pass a hashmap object from response of one test step to the request of another test step in a test case?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I tried using `context.testCase.setPropertyValue(a,b)`, but this is applicable only if parameters are of string type. I am receiving a hashmap which I have to use in another test step. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of `metaClass` groovy property to add a property in the object without using `setPropertyValue`:

```
def map = ['b':'c']
context.testCase.metaClass.yourMapProp = map
```

Then in another groovy testStep you can get it using:

```
log.info context.testCase.yourMapProp // prints INFO:{b=c}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: I have to use the hasmap in my json request, how to use this in that?

Comment: @ErAshishTrivedi can you provide more detail in your question, in what way? do you want to create a json based on map structure, and add this in a specific field of your json?